# Неконкретно работает equalTo в Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework-2, php, zend2, select, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Почти целый день потратил, чтобы найти правильный запрос для вывода данных через JOIN TableGateway. В итоге получилось так:

```
$result = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($id) {
        $select
            ->columns(array(
                'title',
                'image',
            ))
            ->join('album', 'album.id = photo.album_id', array(
                'phone',
                'email'
            ))->where->equalTo('photo.album_id', $id);
    });
    print_r($result);
    return $result->toArray( );
```

Выбираю из двух таблиц колонки title, image, phone, email по album.id, где photo.album_id = $id из аргумента функции. При попытке посмотреть результат видно, что формируется запрос вида:

```
SELECT `photo`.`title` AS `title`, `photo`.`image` AS `image`, `album`.`phone` AS `phone`, `album`.`email` AS `email` FROM `photo` INNER JOIN `album` ON `album`.`id` = `photo`.`album_id` WHERE `photo`.`album_id` = :where1
```

Проблема в этой строке:
    WHERE `photo`.`album_id` = :where1

Почему-то она формируется некорректно... Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема была в другом... Запрос проходил и все нужные данные записывались в массив. На экране же высвечивался массив без половины ячеек. Это меня и смущало... Оказывается я забыл объявить переменные в Model. В итоге:

```
public $image;

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
  $this->image = (isset($data['image'])) ? $data['image'] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->and
->equalTo('photo.album_id', $id);
```